# Magento 2.2; Show left.phtml in Anchor Categories

Tags: magento2.2, layered-navigation

This template (Catalog Module) displays a link that redirects to the parent category; but it looks that it only shows in non-anchor categories.

Does anyone know a way to implement it in anchor categories? I have tried already by means of xml customizations but I cannot get it to work.